# How can i get each user data for multiple user in every team that i got in firebase (node.js)

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-firestore

I got a function written in NODE.JS on firebase that gives me the details for all the teams, where logged user is assigned to:

```
exports.getTeams = (req, res) => {
let teams = [];
db
    .collection("teams")
    .where("members", "array-contains" , req.user.user_id)
    .get()
    .then((data) => {
        data.forEach((doc) => {
            teams.push({
                teamId: doc.id,
                createdAt: doc.data().createdAt,
                leadId: doc.data().leadId,
                members: doc.data().members,
                name: doc.data().name 
            });
        });
        return res.status(200).json(teams);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.status(500).json({error: err.code})
    })
}
```

A 'members' is an array with every userId - those ids are unique ids by which we can filter.
In this case:

```
[uETl8OOisUQLRtmCHoOdy1bsQvf1, QOfg07fDa1X63ao30fq3vqUSU5f2]
```

How could I get the details for every user in this array such as first&last name, email, etc.
As far as I know, I should return a promise with the users, but how to assign them respectively to the correct teams.

Sample users collection:
[image]

Sample teams collection:
[image]

Error code:
[image]

Comment: Where are stored the users data (first & last name, email, ...)? In a dedicated Firestore collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to:

1. Get all the teams a user is part of.
2. All the members of those teams

```js
exports.getTeams = async (req: any, res: any) => {
  // QuerySnapshot of documents which matched the condition
  const teamsSnap = await admin.firestore().collection("teams").where("members", "array-contains", req.user.user_id).get()
  // Array containing data about all teams
  const teams = teamsSnap.docs.map((team) => ({
    teamId: team.id,
    createdAt: team.data().createdAt,
    leadId: team.data().leadId,
    members: team.data().members,
    name: team.data().name
  }))
   
  // Getting all member IDs by running a lot on teams array above
  // and creating a single array of all memberIds
  let memberIds = []
  teams.forEach((team) => {
    team.forEach((member) => {
      if (!memberIds.includes(member)) memberIds.push(member)
    })
  })

  // Request members' documents
  const requests = memberIds.map(m => admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(m).get())

  // If IDs of document ID are not same as user's UID and
  // the UID is present in the document as a field 'userId',
  // then change your query to this:
  const requests = memberIds.map(m => admin.firestore().collection("users").where("userId", "==", m).get())
  // You also need to access `docs[0]` in the map method below.

  // Array of DocumentSnapshots
  const membersSnap = await Promise.all(requests)
  // Array of User documents
  const memberDocs = membersSnap.map((m) => m.data())

  //const memberDocs = membersSnap.map((m) => m.docs[0].data())

  /* Parse your data here */ 

  return res.status(200).json(teams);
}
```

I just made a small assumption that all member documents are in a collection "users" but make sure you replace it. After you have all `memberDocs`, parse/filter them and return the necessary data to client.

Additionally, you might want to remove duplicates from the `memberIds` array as if you have same member in many teams, it'll end up fetching their documents that many times.

**Edit:**

I ran the code above and got this:

[image]

The first one is undefined because I had not document with key `u0`.

Comment: As you correctly assumed - all the members are in "users" collection, however, the array returns [undefined, undefined...] instead of user details. Could you explain me please, how the last 3 assignments work?

Comment: @Kubens95 I'll add some more comments in the code meanwhile can you tell me which array logs `undefined` ?

Comment: the last one returns [undefined, undefined...], the previous one returns doc.snapshot with many undefined values, the first one returns an object with few Promise { <pending> }

Comment: @Kubens95 just to confirm, in users collection the key of documents is same as UID of member right?

Comment: No, you need to filter them by statement .where("userId", "==", m) in the first assignment instead by doc(m). However, when i've done it, i received unhandled promise rejection.

Comment: @Kubens95 do notice that I've made the function `async` see the first line. Also please share a screenshot of that error. Can you also share a screenshot of sample document from users collection and teams collections and highlight the target fields ? I've added some more clarification

Comment: @Kubens95 yep, try the updated answer. `const memberDocs = membersSnap.map((m) => m.docs[0].data())`. Also change the query. Just see [this revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68453571/revisions)